# I've heard something like "young pop" as a synonym for "young man/people". Is it right?

Tags: british-english, orthography

I've heard something like "young pop" as a synonym for "young man/people". Is it right? How do you spell "pop" in that context?

Comment: It's *young pup* - not normally plural, because you usually say it to just one person at a time.

Comment: I would have never have made the leap from "pop" to "pup", but I think you're right.

Comment: A colleague complains that he's "plomp," so I would have understood "young pop" ("yong pop" is how he'd actually say it) as soon as he uttered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @FumbleFingers in the comments, the word you probably heard was "pup", not "pop".  "Pop" is not correct here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is right.

Other synonyms are: young buck, beau, swain, etc.

Comment: Hi Ankit, welcome to ELU. I don't know why someone downvoted your answer, but I absolutely agree your three alternatives. Where I see your sequence as going progressively back in time, with *young pup* being the most recent (but even that's a bit "dated" IMHO).

Comment: +0 synonyms are good, but "it is right" not so much -- spelling is wrong, as you pointed out FF

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Just a little question to make it sure, I have heard it from British as a friendly joke only, but could it have a negative meaning somewhere else?

Comment: -1 because "young pop" is clearly **not** "right".